# The order of double integration of the $\int_0^\infty \frac{2a^2}{x^2 + a^2} (\int_0^1 \cos(yx) dy)dx$.

Tags: definite-integrals

I have integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{2a^2}{x^2 + a^2} \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ after the next transformation $\frac{\sin x}{x} = \frac{1}{x} \int_0^1 x\cos(yx) dy = \int_0^1 \cos(yx) dy$ I get a double integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{2a^2}{x^2 + a^2} (\int_0^1 \cos(yx) dy)dx$.

Am I correct in assuming that I can present it in this form $\int_0^1 dy\int_0^\infty \frac{2a^2}{x^2 + a^2}\cos(yx) dx$ ? where the general function f(x,y) is integrated by x (with appropriate integration bounds) and only then integrated by y? As far as I know I correct, but I am still confused by the fact that the integral $ \int_0^1 \cos(yx) dy $ is inside  of this one $\int_0^\infty \frac{2a^2}{x^2 + a^2} dx$ and thats why I can't integrate function $\cos(yx)$ by x until I integrate it by y over [0 1].

Comment: No, $\cos(yx)$ must be integrated with respect to $y$ first since it's inside the other integral. Afterall, it's useless to do what you did...

Comment: Why using a double integral ? The problem is quite simple

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{2a^2}{x^2 + a^2} \int_0^1 \cos(yx) dydx$ can be rearranged as
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^1\frac{2a^2}{x^2 + a^2} \cos(yx) dydx$$
Now we can change the order of integration as
$$ \int_0^1\int_0^\infty\frac{2a^2}{x^2 + a^2} \cos(yx) dxdy$$
No further simplification is possible than
$$ 2a^2\int_0^1\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(yx)}{x^2 + a^2} dxdy$$